# Django -how to make a combobox depenedent of the choice of other combobox

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

i have 2 dropdown lists on my form , the second combobox related of the choice of other combobox 
the source code of forms.py

```
v_type = forms.ChoiceField( choices=VEHICLE_TYPE,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
v_sub_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VEHICLE_SOUS_TYPE,widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

the data of coices are just into a list variable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0rxX.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax call to populate the v_sub_type options based on onchange event of v_type